# How to investigate why a computer stops a TCP connection?

Tags: networking, tcp, sockets

I've just written [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74567) on another StackExchange site, but I was advised to ask the same question here.

I would like to broaden the question: how can I know why a host closes a TCP socket connection, requested by another host? ((Event) logs, network monitoring, ...)

Comment: Usually logging is not that detailed, so there is no way to do this retrospectively. The common way to analyze network problems is to capture the traffic with Wireshark/tshark. You can configure it to only capture the traffic to the problematic host and let it write to a limited set of files (so the oldest data is overwritten, otherwise the capture file will grow until you stop capturing).

Answer (score 0):

Some broad answers for the broad question, as these are typical steps I perform in the same situation:

1. Tail `/var/log/{messages,secure}` during the client connection attempt
2. Check `/etc/hosts.deny` for the IP of the client
3. Perform a packet capture (tcpdump, wireshark) at both ends to ensure the Server receives the Client SYN, and it's not a middle hop rejecting/blocking the request
4. Look for open and listening sockets on the Server end (`netstat` or similar) before client connection attempts
5. Check Client and Server firewall rules (including security groups et al if in cloud) to ensure inbound/outbound connections are permitted on the attempted IP/port pair
6. Try the same connection but with a well established tool (e.g. `nc/netcat`) - is it your code/tool that fails to establish a connection on that IP/port or other tools too?

Regarding your original question on the other site, are you able to establish a full 3-way tcp handshake, but the disconnect (RST/FIN packet?) occurs once sending data? If so, that might point to the application protocol above TCP not liking the data sent and deciding to kill the connection.